# Convert flash chart (fusionchart) to image in php

Tags: php, image, flash, fusioncharts

I am using an older version of FusionCharts in one of my web applications (developed in php). It is working fine and I do not want to change or update it.

But the flash charts do not work on mobile devices and I need to find a easy way to convert the swf into an image (gif, jpeg, png).

Do you know a solution for this issue that can be easily implemented in php?

Thank you!

Dan.

Comment: Updating your chart would be the best option to get your chart work in Mobile Devices(IOS,Android, Blackberry etc.).
You will only need to change the FusionChart JS files in your application and you are ready to go.

Comment: You can refer-
http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2013/03/how-to-save-charts-as-images-at-server-side/
.
Export the image and show the image in your page can also resolve your issue. Update is a must for you, FC Eval has many features worth updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of FusionCharts are you using?

You can easily upgrade to the latest version of FusionCharts v3.3.1 SR2 without changing your code. The latest version provides you with JavaScript variant of Fusioncharts which render on all devices irrespective of the presence of Flash player. By doing this, you can also ensure the same look and feel in all the devices. Refer : http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/index.html?Introduction/Upgrading32.html

If you are using the version of FusionCharts which provides you with an export option, then you may export your Flash chart to Image and then show that image (which is not a good solution).
For information on exporting Flash charts, refer http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/exporting-image/server-side/ECServerSave.html